# \<space> creates different spacing on different positions

Tags: spacing

The command `\<space>` (as far as I know) is used to create a small white space. However, it seems to behave in a weird way when you put it at the end of a line of code; sometimes the space *is* created and sometimes it *is not*. More specifically,

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\
```

sometimes has a white space and sometimes it doesn't, while

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\
```

never has. See the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 

\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 

\hrule
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 

\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 
\hrule
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
\ 

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p\ 

\hrule
\end{document}
```

which creates this picture:

[image: The letters at the end have different alignment]

Clearly, the letters are not aligned in the same way every time and there seems to be an extra white space on some occasions.

I am wondering why and when this exactly happens. Thank you.

Comment: What has happened here is that an explicit extra space has been inserted.  The end of line is euivalent to a typed space and the `\ ` on the next line is another space.  (La)TeX will compress multiple consecutive typed spaces into a single space, but it will not compress explicit spaces.  You would have gotten the same result if the lines had ended with `... o p \ `.  Multiple spaces can actually be forced with `\ \ \ `.  There are other ways of producing multiple spaces; just remember that only consecutive spaces typed with the space bar will be compressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collapsing runs of spaces happens in the early scanning of *characters* as they are read from a file before tokenisation. It does not apply to tokens (which is why you often need `%` in macros to prevent extra white space tokens). So `\` adds a token that acts very similar to a space token during typesetting. Compare

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a  b

a \ b

a { }b

\end{document}
```

where in the first line there is just a single space token (as the second space character was never tokenized_ ). The second line has a space token and a `\` primitive csname token.  The third line has two space tokens.

The other aspect to your example is that you do not have any `\<space>` tokens in the example, spaces at ends of lines are removed before tokenization so you have `\<newlinechar>` which is `\<character 10>`

LaTeX in fact defines

```
\def\^^M{\ }
```

so the `\<endofline>` at end of line expands in one step to `\<space>` and makes the same output, but if you define it differently then you can see

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\ =S
\let\^^M=L
\begin{document}

a\ b
\


a\ b\

a b
\


a b%
\

\end{document}
```

This makes a space token, a `\<space>` and `\<newline>`  show as space, S and L respectively and you can see that forms as you show have two tokens at the end of the line.

Comment: In the last example you seem to have demonstrated that a space at the beginning of a line is ignored (except that it does cause whatever is at the end of the previous line to be tokenized).  But not sure why there isn't an "S" at the end of the second "paragraph".

Comment: @barbarabeeton not sure why you would expect S the second para ends with backslash end-of-line, so you get L

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  But then why don't paras 1 and 3 end with "LL"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton because L is produced by `\<newline>` and those paragraphs  only have one command at the end, what would make the second L?

Comment: Okay.  I was (incorrectly) interpreting the "actual" newlines as `\<newline>`, which they're not.  (And `\ ` isn't the same as a typed space, which is where this all started.)  Okay.  I'm being dense.  But it's important for one to recognize these as four different things, which may not be immediately obvious.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Thank you! This is very enlightening!

Could you also briefly explain how `\^^M` works? I've never seen this before!

Comment: `^^` followed by a character is replaced by the character with code changed by 64 (the same as the control key on a keyboard) so `\^^M` is \<character 13> which you can't normally type because M is character 77 in ascii and unicode

Comment: Oh, this is intersesting! Thank you!